# PLS-00049 BAD BIND VARIABLE on triggers on columns with a specific collation

Tags: oracle

I've modified the collation of a column in a table of mine and the trigger built on that table does not bind that column any more.
I have two examples of code, one working and the other one not.

I'm using Oracle 12.2 version

```
CREATE USER "MYUSER" IDENTIFIED EXTERNALLY;

CREATE TABLE "MYUSER"."TESTTAB"
( 
  "Id" RAW(16),
  "TEXT" VARCHAR2(10) COLLATE BINARY_CI
);

CREATE TABLE "MYUSER"."TESTTAB2"
( 
  "Id" RAW(16),
  "TEXT" VARCHAR2(10)
);
```

> This trigger is not compiled correctly, with an error in binding :New."TEXT" variable...
>   Error(3,4): PLS-00049: bad bind variable 'NEW.TEXT' 
>   Error(5,1): PLS-00049: bad bind variable 'NEW.TEXT'

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER "MYUSER"."TR_TESTTAB"
BEFORE INSERT OR UPDATE
ON "MYUSER"."TESTTAB"
REFERENCING NEW AS New OLD AS Old
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN

If :New."TEXT" is null
then
:New."TEXT" := 'A';
end if;

END "TR_TESTTAB";
```

While this one is compiled correctly...

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER "MYUSER"."TR_TESTTAB2" 
BEFORE INSERT OR UPDATE
ON "MYUSER"."TESTTAB2"
REFERENCING NEW AS New OLD AS Old
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN

If :New."TEXT" is null
then
:New."TEXT" := 'A';
end if;

END "TR_TESTTAB2";
```

It seems as the column, after collation setting, were named differently...
Can you help me ?

Comment: Not related to your question but something that it seems you don't know and which is good to know (IMO). Oracle identifiers are all upper case by default, so you don't need to surround them with quote marks in your SQL. You do need quotes if you want mixed case identifiers but that is not encouraged.